# ASP.NET Form View IF on Updating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to run an if before updating a form view; 
if yes then..."message" & cancel update query
if no continue update query.

i've tried this but i'm getting a "obeject instance not set to null instance......" on the first line of the if? and the item updates regardless

```
Private Sub FormView2_ItemUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles FormView2.ItemUpdating
    Dim status As TextBox = FormView1.FindControl("ApprovalStatusTextBox")


    If status.Text = "approved" Or "denied" Then
        e.Cancel = True
        lblupdaterequest.Text = "you cannot update this request as it has already been responded to"
    Else
        HolidayDetailsdatasource.Update()
    End If
```

Anyone aware of a better was of achieving something like this?

exact error:

```
   System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   Source=WebApplication1
   StackTrace:
   at WebApplication1.HolidayApprovalDetails.DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(Object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e) in line 32
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnItemUpdating(DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleUpdate(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Can you post the real and clean error message? Maybe copy & paste? And it sounds like your status textbox does not exist or is null? Can you debug that?

Comment: Where is this TextBox, i mean in which Template(f.e. [`EditItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.edititemtemplate.aspx)?  `FormView` has three different [`FormViewModes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewmode.aspx). Apart from that i would suggest to use [`FormViewUpdateEventArgs.NewValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) instead

Comment: Is this TextBox readonly? Then i would suggest to use [FormViewUpdateEventArgs.OldValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx). Are you sure that you've spelled `ApprovalStatusTextBox` correctly? Can you show the relevant part of your FormView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can at least see that you are retrieving the value of the status TextBox from '**FormView1**', while your sub ItemUpdating is referring to '**FormView2**'.

After changing this, try adding a message box before the if, to make sure you got the right value you wanted:

```
MsgBox(status.Text)
```

Hopefully, it helps you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
If status IsNot Nothing AndAlso (status.Text = "approved" OrElse status.Text = "denied") Then
```

Comment: it doesn't crash anymore. but it still updates regardless of the "status" am I missing something?